# zxing barcode - how to embed the scanner(intent) with other layouts

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

The code below works for me. However, how could I embed it with other layouts from another activity?

Basically, The screen will be splitted in two parts:
Fist one will contain a header and shared buttons to use in other screens;
Second one will be the Barcode scanner or any other screen.

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

};

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        // Handle successful scan
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Handle cancel
    }
}
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn no way to do this. You are invoking a third-party app and can't control how it looks.

Comment: Does Android not support calling thid-party app inside of another app like web frames? Anyway @Sean Owen..thanks a million

Comment: `Does Android not support calling thid-party app inside of another app like web frames?` **NO** :)